# How does IPinfo show json data using file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

Today I was using an api for getting information for a specific IP address and it works fine.

```
file_get_contents("https://ipinfo.io/172.217.19.206");
```

From this I get normal json output which I can json_decode

{ "ip": "172.217.19.206", "hostname": "ams16s31-in-f14.1e100.net", "city": "", "region": "", "country": "US", "loc": "37.7510,-97.8220", "org": "AS15169 Google LLC" }

But the thing that I do not understand is if I visit the page https://ipinfo.io/172.217.19.206 using the browser then I do not see this output at all. I always thought file_get_contents gets the source of the page?

Comment: remote site can detect browser vs bot

Comment: ah I see I thought it was more complicated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website used useragent method for handling this.

You can test it by Postman.

Only set null value for `User-Agent` in Headers section and send get request to that url.

[image: Postman Example]

Comment: Thanks for the example I understand how it was done now and it all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in our documentation here: https://ipinfo.io/developers#json-response

> We try to automatically detect when someone wants to call our API vs
>   view our website, and send back the appropriate JSON response rather
>   than HTML. We do this based on the user agent for known popular
>   programming languages, tools and frameworks

There are a few other bits of "magic". We'll always send JSON if there's a URL callback parameter, or an AJAX header.

You can also force a JSON response by adding `/json` to the end of the URL, or sending an `Accept: application/json` header.

Comment: Oh I had no idea it would be documented on the website thanks :)